# JAX-RS ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, jax-rs

I'm trying to call a JAX-RS webservice with ajax using jquery
I encountred a vital problem that the invocation of the method has happened but the I can't get the data

```
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.2:9080/TestJMSWeb/jaxrs/categories/",function(data){
alert("success"+data);
});
```

this code should be executed on the phone with phonegap

the webservice is returning json array data I'm wondering why I can't get that data while the call is happining and I see the message of the exection of the method in the console.
could you please tell me what should I do to fix my problem I'm very anxious
and thanks in advance.

Comment: Dojo toolkit? It looks like jQuery call.

Comment: no sorry I'm confusing just I tested the call with jquery but if it works I'm going to change it with dojo function

Comment: give your error.  it'll help to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

"I can't get that data while the call is happining" - I am not sure what is the problem. Maybe you problem is related to the fact that AJAX calls are asynchronous, so you need to wait for AJAX request returns back data from server. During the request you'll not see any data.

Comment: the callback method is not running at all. isn't a problem of configuration sould I make an ajax proxy ?

Comment: to the expression you have add $.getJSON("YOUR_URL", YOUR_ALERT_FUN)
.error(function() { alert("error"); }) and check if request is succesfull or not